# How to read input from user with unknown length?

Tags: java, loops, dynamic, input, delimiter

I want to enter a string of numbers, delimited by ",". I don't know how long it will be. The input will be passed to the program and will end with the letter "x".

JAVA!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fromUserSum {
/// input : 1,2,4x   from user
/// output : 7
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int sumTotal=0;
        while(scan.nextByte() != 'x') {
            num = scan.nextInt();
            sumTotal += num;
        }
        System.out.println(sumTotal);
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

PLEASE help! :)

//////////////

```
public class fromUserSum {
/// input : 1,2,4x   from user
/// output : 7
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a list of numbers in following format: 1,2,3,4x");
            userInput = scan.next();
        } while (!userInput.matches("(?:\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)x") || !userInput.matches("\\d+( \\d+)*x"));

        scan.close();
        String[] numberStrings;
        if (userInput.contains(",")) {
        numberStrings = userInput.replace("x", "").split(","); // 4x is now 4 and split by ','
        } else {
            numberStrings = userInput.replace("x", "").split(" ");
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for (String i : numberStrings) {
            sum += Integer.valueOf(i);
        }

        System.out.println("The sum of all numbers in the list is: " + sum);

}
}
```

Comment: OP! PLEASE use a self-contained example stating how your existing code didn't work with stack traces if applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value");
        String string = sc.nextLine();
        string = string.replace("x", "");
        String[] strArray = string.split(",");
        for (String str : strArray) {
                result += Integer.valueOf(str);
        }
        System.out.println("Result is " + result);
    }
```

**Input is** `1,2,3,4x`

**Output is**  `Result is 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.Scanner;
class MainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int sum=0;
        Console c=System.console();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(c.readLine());
        scan.useDelimiter("[,x]");
        while(scan.hasNextInt())
            sum+=scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job as well. Additionally it tells the user what input is expected and if the entered list does not match the format.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Scanner userInputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput;

    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter a list of numbers in following format: 1,2,3,4x or 1 2 3 4x");
        userInput = userInputScanner.nextLine();
    } while (!(userInput.matches("\\d+(,\\d+)*x") || userInput.matches("\\d+( \\d+)*x")));

    userInputScanner.close();

    final String[] numberStrings = userInput.replace("x", "").split("[, ]");
    int sum = 0;

    for (final String numberString : numberStrings) {
        sum += Integer.valueOf(numberString);
    }

    System.out.println("The sum of all numbers in the list is: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Working great thank you, can you please explain a bit more about the userInput.matches("(?:\\d+(?:,\\d+)*)x")        what are the signs you chose? i see x but what about the others

Comment: This is a regular expression. It can be written even simpler: `\d+(,\d+)*x`. `\d+` means one or more digits. `,\d+` means a comma followed by one or more digits. `()*` means that the things inside the brackets can be repeated infinitely, but they don't have to. `x` means a single "x".

Comment: ok , so if I make like !userInput.matches("(?:\\d+(?: \\d+)*)x")    does it means I need to put an expression like 1 2 3 4x ?

Comment: It introduces a non-capturing group. But since you only want to match the regex it is not needed. And yes, `!userInput.matches("(?:\\d+(?: \\d+)*)x")` accepts something like `1 2 3 4x`. But better write it shorter: `!userInput.matches("\\d+( \\d+)*x")`.

Comment: I edited my post and aas you can see I tried to do that but I get wrong answer since it only catch the last integer: 1 3 4 5x return 5

Comment: Replace `userInputScanner.next()` with `userInputScanner.nextLine()` and `!userInput.matches("\\d+(,\\d+)*x") || !userInput.matches("\\d+( \\d+)*x")` with `!(userInput.matches("\\d+(,\\d+)*x") || userInput.matches("\\d+( \\d+)*x"))`. I have updated my answer as well.